# Can I sandbox a namespace that uses static data?

Tags: c++, static, singleton, extensibility

Say I have (pretty large) C++ module in a `namespace foo` which has a lot (well, at least one) of static data, namespace-global data and Singletons and so forth, spread across a myriad of files and directories. Is there any way to "sandbox" that entire thing in order to run independent versions at the same time (in the same process, that is). How many versions are to be run will be decided at runtime.

I thought about wrapping everything in several namespaces (e.g. `bar1::foo`, `bar2::foo`, ...), but that is a) not possible, since I don't want to touch all files and b) it would not enable me to have an arbitrary number at runtime.

---

Update: I was thinking perhaps I could create separate thread for each version, but I'm not that well versed with threads.

Comment: As a side remark: No, I didn't write `foo` and Yes, I know statics/Singletons are evil.

Comment: +1, had a very similar problem once with a 3rd-party C interface. Didn’t find a good solution (my solution involved multiple macro-generated namespaces).

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting your `foo` code inside a shared object. During runtime you can load and unload that shared object as often as you desire.

For an initial reference on dynamic loading of shared object, take a peek at http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the manpage for `dlopen` tells us: "If the same library is loaded again with dlopen(), the same file handle is returned." So that this approach does work directly. Also `libld` is smart enough to recognise sym- and hard-links. However, copying the shared object library does the trick. Nevertheless, due to the nature of this we are limited to talking through C (instead of C++) interfaces with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have created a namespace with state, this is bad, you want to use a class for this use case you should be able to change it reasonably easily so that it a class

So where you have had

```
namespace foo{
    int state;
    int func();
}

foo::func();
```

you need

```
class foo{
    int state;
    int func();
};

foo foo1;
foo1.func();
```

Comment: No. I'm not, `foo` is huge! Hence the question.

Comment: But the problem you are describing is identical to the use case of a class, why exactly can't you use a class?

Comment: @bitmask namespaces and classes are very similar constructs just classes can be duplicated, if foo is huge then having multiple copies is still duplicating it: exactly the same as the class. Maybe it will help you break the problem down too.

Comment: Because the changes would be overwhelming (again: `foo` is huge). By the way, this is also problematic for smaller example. Think of objects inside `foo`, you would have to communicate to which `foo` object they belong in all calls.

Comment: But classes can also have object inside of them, and they can have class wide singletons, it might be ugly but it isn't going to be any nicer than your impossible namespace duplication idea.

Comment: Look at your small example, that doesn't even have nested types, how much you already had to change. Now think about roughly 40 MB of source code. Also, "impossible" is something to be careful with in programming :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8805/discussion-between-bitmask-and-111111)